# How to train own model and test it with spacy

Tags: nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using the below code to train an already existing spacy ner model. However,  I dont get correct results on tests:

What I am missing?

```
import spacy
import random
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
from spacy.language import EntityRecognizer

train_data = [
    ('Who is Rocky babu?', [(7, 16, 'PERSON')]),
    ('I like London and Berlin.', [(7, 13, 'LOC'), (18, 24, 'LOC')])
]

nlp = spacy.load('en', entity=False, parser=False)
ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab, entity_types=['PERSON', 'LOC'])

for itn in range(5):
    random.shuffle(train_data)
    for raw_text, entity_offsets in train_data:
        doc = nlp.make_doc(raw_text)
        gold = GoldParse(doc, entities=entity_offsets)

        nlp.tagger(doc)
        nlp.entity.update([doc], [gold])
Now, When i try to test the above model by using the below code, I don't get the expected output.

text = ['Who is Rocky babu?']

for a in text:
        doc = nlp(a)
        print("Entities", [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
My output is as follows:

Entities []
whereas my expected output is as follows:

Entities [('Rocky babu', 'PERSON')]
Can someone please tell me what I'm missing ?
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what results you are getting and what results you are expecting?

Comment: My output is as follows:

Currently, I am getting the entities as blank when I use the same training data as test data.. Entities [].. Whereas what I am expecting is as below:

Entities [('Rocky babu', 'PERSON')]
Can someone please tell me what I'm missing ?

Comment: [Here is a sample code and training json data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55117950/8398247)

Answer (score 1):

Could you retry with

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', entity=False, parser=False)
```

If that gives an error because you don't have that model installed, you can run

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

on the commandline first.

And ofcourse keep in mind that for a proper training of the model, you'll need many more examples for the model to be able to generalize!

Comment: thanks for your response. I changed the code to include the line you gave above but still after training, while testing my model doesn't currently identify ROCKY BABU as person. I have a few questions for which I hope you can help me with answers. Is my code above to train and test correct ? Is my understanding correct that using the same line to train/test should yield me the correct entities ?

Comment: The code is correct in principle, when I replace your definition of `nlp =  ` with my line of code for `nlp`, it runs correctly.

Though the code is technically correct, keep in mind that for real-world problems you would need at least a few hundred of examples to train your model on. In this case, it might not always be so that your model will be able to replicate each training example exactly. Instead, a ML model should generalize the patterns it sees in the training data without overfitting on that same data.