# Spacy annotation tool entities indices

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, spacy, entities

How can I read my annotated data in Spacy?

1) My annotated data's form:

```
  "annotation": [
    [
      79,
      99,
      "Nom complet"
    ],
```

2) Annotated data's form in the script:

```
  "annotation": [
    {
      "label": [
        "Companies worked at"
      ],
      "points": [
        {
          "start": 1749,
          "end": 1754,
          "text": "Oracle"
        }
      ]
    },
```

3) How can I change this code that can read my annotated data?

```
for line in lines:
    data = json.loads(line)
    text = data['text']
    entities = []
    for annotation in data['annotation']:
        #only a single point in text annotation.
        point = annotation['points'][0]
        labels = annotation['label']
        # handle both list of labels or a single label.
        if not isinstance(labels, list):
            labels = [labels]

        for label in labels:
            dataturks indices are both inclusive [start, end] but spacy is not [start, end)
    entities.append(([0], [1],[2]))


    training_data.append((text, {"entities" : entities}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Training Json:-
`[{
        "text": "This Labor-Contract ('CONTRACT'), effective as of May 12, 2017 (“Effective Date”), is made by and between Client-ABC, Inc. ('Client-ABC'), having its principal place of business at 1030 Client-ABC Street, Atlanta, GA 30318, USA and Supplier-ABC (“Supplier”), having a place of business at 100 Park Avenue, Miami, 10178, USA (hereinafter referred to individually as “Party” and collectively as “Parties”).",
        "entities": [
            [
                50,
                62,
                "EFFECTIVE_DATE"
            ],
            [
                106,
                116,
                "VENDOR_NAME"
            ],
            [
                181,
                203,
                "VENDOR_ADDRESS"
            ],
            [
                205,
                212,
                "VENDOR_CITY"
            ],
            [
                214,
                216,
                "VENDOR_STATE"
            ],
            [
                217,
                222,
                "VENDOR_POSTAL_CODE"
            ],
            [
                224,
                227,
                "VENDOR_COUNTRY"
            ]
        ]
    },{second training data}]`

Code for training custom :-

```
training_pickel_file = "training_pickel_file.json"
with open(training_pickel_file) as input:
TRAIN_DATA = json.load(input)
for annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
   for ent in annotations["entities"]:
      ner.add_label(ent[2])
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    for itn in range(n_iter):
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}
        for a in TRAIN_DATA:
            doc = nlp.make_doc(a["text"])
            gold = GoldParse(doc, entities = a["entities"])
            nlp.update([doc], [gold], drop =0.5, sgd=optimizer, losses = losses)
        print('Losses', losses)
```