# spaCy 2.0: Loading Training Data from excel file Custom NER Model issues

Tags: python, xlrd, spacy

I have made a custom NER model using spaCy by loading the training data from a text file in the prescribed format and the model is working fine, However If I am trying to load training data from excel file we get the output model but does not getting the entities(no output and also no error).
Model from the training data in text file is working perfectly giving proper outputs but not getting results if loading training data from xlsx file.
No problem in datatypes(same for both the cases).
Even If I am writing the same into a text file and then loading it , facing same issue

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: import xlrd
loc =(". ./training_data.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
TRAIN_DATA = []
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
allRows = []
nrows = sheet.nrows
count = 0
for i in range(1, nrows):
    row = sheet.row_values(i)
    obj = {'sentence': '', 'data': []}
    tup = tuple(row[1:5])
    if (len(row[0]) != 0):
        count += 1
        obj['sentence'] = row[0]
        obj['data'].append(tup)
        allRows.append(obj)
    else:
        allRows[count - 1]['data'].append(tup)

Comment: for example in allRows:  
    entities = []

    for entity in example['data']:  # iterate over the entities
        text, label, start, end = entity  # ('want', '@command', 2, 6)
        label = label.split('@')[1].upper()  # not necessary, but nicer
        end = end - 1  # correct the end character index
        entities.append((int(start), int(end), label))

        #x=json.dumps(entities,indent=4)
         # add training example of (text, annotations) tuple
    TRAIN_DATA.append((example['sentence'] ,{'entities':entities}))

Comment: [Training custom entities from json training data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55117950/8398247)

Answer (score 0):

Please write the code after 4 space you will get proper format in stack overflow or ctrl+k then write the code.