# Direction on feature extraction in an unstructured document with Python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, spacy, text-extraction

Project Background:
I'm quite new to NLP so please forgive me if my problem seems unreasonably complicated. I am trying to extract some features, like company names, some money value and names of individuals from a public company listing document, which large body of text (300+ pages).

Text parsed into the program looks something like this:
"In this motion, Company A Holdings (The "Company"), was sponsored by Company B Limited. John Doe, the chairman of the company, has approved of this activity"

The expected outcome looks something like this: 
The Company: Company A Holdings
Sponsor: Company B Limited
Chairman: John Doe

Since all documents came in PDF form, I have parsed them in as text. Performed some NER with Spacy with the document I have, and based on the looks of the NER result, it had successfully recognised all the entities that I needed. (I.E. It recognised Company A Holdings, Company B Limited and John Doe)

How should I approach the said goal? I don't have a massive amount of files to train the model (currently around 30 ish documents), a general direction or example of modules on how to tackle the problem would be highly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Which NER model are you using for entity extraction?

Comment: I'm using spacy if that's what you're asking?

Comment: No, I am asking which model of spacy are you using like 'en', 'en_core_web_sm', etc. ?

Comment: Oh my apologies, I'm using "en_core_web_md" model.

Comment: You should train your own custom entity model, you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083376/spacy-annotation-tool-entities-indices/55117950#55117950) for custom entity model creation.

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late reply Chandan. Does that mean building a list of json manually to train the custom NER? Does repeated occurrence of an entry make a difference to the model? Thank you so much.

Comment: No, repeated occurrence of entities in training data doesn't make any difference.