# Problems Redacting Names from Text Using Python 3.x and SpaCy

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have some text fragments in which I want to redact certain names, but not all names. I played around with some string tools in python, then founds spaCy. I installed spaCy version 2.1.4 with Python 3.6.6. I then wrote a little program based on some articles on the Internet and the docs.

The problems I have encountered is that spaCy does well with full names (first last or first middle last) but not with just first names, as you can see from the code and output.

redacted_text.py:

```
test="This picture is also a test of redacting text. I will add some names and see if they are redacted. First, let's talk about Sally Marriott. We could then mention Adam Westin Marriott. Maybe Hanna and John need an honorable mention. Then, of course, there are Diana and Meagan."

hidden_people=['Sally Magilicudy Marriott', 'Sally Francis Magilicudy', 'Adam Westin Marriott', 'Diana Francis Marriott', 'Meagan Marriott', 'Sally Marriott', 'Sally Magilicudy', 'Adam Marriott', 'Diana Marriott', 'Meagan Marriott', 'Sally', 'Adam', 'Diana', 'Meagan',]

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
docx = nlp(test)
redacted_sentences = []    
for ent in docx.ents:
    print("ent=%s" % ent)
    ent.merge()
for token in docx:
    print("token.string='%s', type=%s" % (token.string, token.ent_type_))
    if (token.string in hidden_people):
    redacted_sentences.append("[REDACTED]") 
    #print("redacted name=%s" % token.string)
    else:
    redacted_sentences.append(token.string)
    #print("did not redact=%s" % token.string)
print("".join(redacted_sentences))
```

output:

```
$ python redacted_text.py 
ent=First
ent=Sally Marriott
ent=Adam Westin Marriott
ent=Hanna
ent=John
ent=Diana
ent=Meagan
token.string='This ', type=
token.string='picture ', type=
token.string='is ', type=
token.string='also ', type=
token.string='a ', type=
token.string='test ', type=
token.string='of ', type=
token.string='redacting ', type=
token.string='text', type=
token.string='. ', type=
token.string='I ', type=
token.string='will ', type=
token.string='add ', type=
token.string='some ', type=
token.string='names ', type=
token.string='and ', type=
token.string='see ', type=
token.string='if ', type=
token.string='they ', type=
token.string='are ', type=
token.string='redacted', type=
token.string='. ', type=
token.string='First', type=ORDINAL
token.string=', ', type=
token.string='let', type=
token.string=''s ', type=
token.string='talk ', type=
token.string='about ', type=
token.string='Sally Marriott', type=PERSON
token.string='. ', type=
token.string='We ', type=
token.string='could ', type=
token.string='then ', type=
token.string='mention ', type=
token.string='Adam Westin Marriott', type=PERSON
token.string='. ', type=
token.string='Maybe ', type=
token.string='Hanna ', type=PERSON
token.string='and ', type=
token.string='John ', type=PERSON
token.string='need ', type=
token.string='an ', type=
token.string='honorable ', type=
token.string='mention', type=
token.string='. ', type=
token.string='Then', type=
token.string=', ', type=
token.string='of ', type=
token.string='course', type=
token.string=', ', type=
token.string='there ', type=
token.string='are ', type=
token.string='Diana ', type=PERSON
token.string='and ', type=
token.string='Meagan', type=GPE
token.string='.', type=
This picture is also a test of redacting text. I will add some names and see if they are redacted. First, let's talk about [REDACTED]. We could then mention [REDACTED]. Maybe Hanna and John need an honorable mention. Then, of course, there are Diana and [REDACTED].
```

The issues are (1) not all first names are recognized as PERSON: Meagan is a GPE, so I can't use the PERSON entity to search in the text, and (2) I cannot use token.string to search my list of names because the Diana token has a trailing space associated with it, but not Meagan or other names.

Would a better approach be to train spaCy on the set of names I want to redact before analyzing the text? Is that possible, and how do I do it- I got lost in the documentation trying to figure out how to train spaCy? Or, is there another approach I should take to redact names from text.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Either add any surname then it will tag as Person or train a [custom entity tagging model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083376/spacy-annotation-tool-entities-indices/55117950#55117950)